# ¿Como crear una función para subir un archivo de n numeros de fileupload?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema de antemano les agradezco su ayuda y su tiempo.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo 5 tabs y dentro de cada tab o pestaña hay un fileupload de html para subir un archivo. Mi pregunta es:

¿Como puedo crear una función donde le pase el id del control para subir el archivo?, ya que en este caso mi código lo repito 5 veces.

Este es mi código para subir el archivo, este corresponde solo a un fileupload para los demás es el mismo código solo le cambio el nombre del control.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $("#fuArchivo1").on('change', function() {

        var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('file', $('#fuArchivo1')[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/script/Guardar_Archivos.ashx',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function() {              
                alert("Archivo subido con exito");
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Por qué no agregas una clase y loopeas sobre los `input file`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hice el submit desde un botón,
  // para que sea más fácil saber cuando se hayan agregado otros files
  $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var fileName = $(this)
      .val()
      .split('\\')
      .pop();
    // obtenemos los input file con la clase '.file-upload'
    var $inputsFile = $('.file-upload');
    var formData = new FormData();
    $inputsFile.each(function(index) {
      // hacemos el append a formData
      formData.append('file' + index, $(this)[0].files[0]);
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: '/script/Guardar_Archivos.ashx',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function() {
        alert('Archivo subido con exito');
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert(err.statusText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Si necesitas hacer el upload en el onChange de los input, deberías agregar un control extras para saber cuando hacer el upload dependiendo de los requerimientos